# Date of Last DBCC checkdb run

Tags: t-sql, dbcc-checkdb, maintenance

Using T-SQL, I can get the last known good DBCC Checkdb through DBCC DBINFO().
My question is, can I find, somewhere in SQL, when the Last DBCC Checkdb Ran? (regardless of being successful or not)

I would need this info to compare the Last date it ran with the last known good DBCC checkdb so that I can take action if the dates don't match.

Since I'm on SQL Express, I can't use SQL Server Agent to run the DBCC checkdb so it can be run randomly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Just because there is no agent does not mean you can't (or shouldn't) schedule regularly nightly or weekly dbcc through other means rather than relying on random, memory, etc. Windows Task Scheduler, PowerShell jobs, etc.

Comment: default trace logs that info provided its not rolled over or recycled. check `EventClass = 116  AND TextData like '%DBCC%'`

Comment: Also, if you're not relying on automation, I have a hard time believing someone is running checkdb manually, getting errors, and deciding not to tell anyone...

Comment: @kin not sure i understand "EventClass = 116 AND TextData like '%DBCC%'" are you talking about using the xp_enumerrorlogs ? I was hoping that there was another way something like the DBINFO() that shows the last known good DBCC.  I want to try to create something automated that will compare the last run with the last known good dates.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I don't want to rely on a schedule, I want to create a function that will compare the last run with the last known good dates and return 0 for Good and 1 for false.

Comment: I am talking about default trace which is on by default.

Comment: @kin, how do you search in tsql through the default trace? without using profiler.

Comment: Ok, so you just want to run dbcc checks when someone remembers? Sounds great. As for querying the default trace, did you search? Here's one example (you'll have to change the where clause of course): https://sqlblog.org/2011/02/02/who-created-that-user

Comment: Or Even better answered http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48053/8783

Comment: some of the comments are amusing, what a pleasure to be a DBA!

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve is to [log information from your default trace into a physical persistent table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2695/maintaining-sql-server-default-trace-historical-events-for-analysis-and-reporting/).

A default trace is like a black box recorder for sql server and is ON by default. It records `116  (EventID )    Audit DBCC Event (Event Description)`.

Only relying on [`dbi_dbccLastKnownGood` for determining of checkdb](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_pfe_blog/2010/02/09/last-known-good-backupdbcc/) ran [**is misleading**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/144375/8783) as `DBCC CHECKDB ('your_db_name') WITH PHYSICAL_ONLY` will update the `dbi_dbccLastKnownGood` along with `DBCC CHECKFILEGROUP`.

The only way to determine of checkdb ran successfully is to actually run it and record all the error messages (if any).

Also, refer to : [What event information can I get by default from SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48052/what-event-information-can-i-get-by-default-from-sql-server) from Aaron Bertrand.

Comment: As I was searching more and more, I found the following:  If I compare "EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog 0,1,N'DBCC CHECKDB', N'MyDB'" against the DBINFO's Last known Good DBCC... Wouldn't that do the job?  If the dates match , it's good, otherwise it's no good.  Do you see a problem with this?

Comment: It would do as well. default trace is less in size as opposed to error log and it has less events logged as well. Also, as I mentioned in my answer, the `dbi_dbccLastKnownGood` is not 100% reliable so use it with caution. Why not schedule a job using powershell and then check the successful output .. instead of relying on something that is not 100% accurate ?

Comment: Powershel requires XP_CMDSHELL and that is a whole other debate and  won't pass here.  Why isn't dbccLastKnowGood 100% reliable?

Comment: Did you read my linked answer ?

Comment: yes I have... and it answered my question