# dbcc checktable will write in my dbcc page (x,9,3) for the field dbi_dbccLastKnownGood

Tags: sql-server, database-internals, dbcc-checkdb

If I run `DBCC CHECKALLOC,DBCC CHECKCATALOG` and `DBCC CHECKTABLE` in all objects it will update my internal page with the actual date in `dbi_dbccLastKnownGood` field?

The main reason of the question is for a db with 14 TB and my window is short so I need lot of windows.

Comment: Does [my answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/144375/8783) help you in your case.

Comment: Yes, i've run a test with a 10 MB filegroup in a 07 GB db ant it's uptaded. Sad Bad True cause all the database is not checked !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Erin Stellato's blog, [What Checks Update dbccLastKnownGood?](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/what-checks-update-dbcclastknowngood/):

> Breaking out the checks between the different commands does not update
>   dbccLastKnownGood – running CHECKDB is the only thing that does

Erin also notes there that `DBCC CHECKFILEGROUP` and `CHECKDB` with the `PHYSICAL_ONLY` option will update `dbccLastKnownGood`.